# Triggering Mail function of php when a button is clicked

Tags: php

I want to trigger `mail()` function of `php` when a button is clicked.

I have tried using;

```
 <button id="Next" type="button" onclick="executeShellScript();" >Next</button>
```

for the `button`. Note the type of button must be always button you cannot use `submit` for my case.

In javascript side

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function executeShellScript(){
           <?php mail(); ?>
        }
    </script>
```

and for php

```
      <?php
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
            global $value;
            $value="100";
         function mail(){
            require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
            require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
            require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
            global $message;
            global $toAddress;
            $toAddress = "xxxx@gmail.com"; //To whom you are sending the mail.
            $messages  = <<<EOT
                <html>
                   <body>
                     Your value is
                     <br>
                     <h1 align="center">
                   </body>
                </html>
            EOT;
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
            $mail->Host        = "mail.xxx.com";
            $mail->Port        = 587;
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );
            $message = $messages.$value.'</h1>';
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Username = "xxx@xxx.com"; // your gmail address
            $mail->Password = "xxxxxxx"; // password
            $mail->SetFrom("xxxxx@xxxx.com");
            $mail->Subject = "Try "; // Mail subject
            $mail->Body    = $message;
            $mail->Address($toAddress);
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: Obligatory first read: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13840429) // This usually requires an AJAX request // And redefining the `mail()` function name doesn't work.

Comment: @mario I understand the difference. But can youu help me to sort out that problem.

Comment: @Niyojoli Your code indicates that you do _not_ understand the difference.  If you did, you wouldn't be attempting to directly invoke a PHP function within Javascript code.

Comment: @PatrickQ  I know this will not work but I should use AJAX request. But the problem is I am not familiar to AJAX. Soo,  can you please help me out.

Comment: So _get_ familiar.  Take the time to _learn_.  Read some tutorials, and then make an attempt.  We're more than happy to help you fix an honest try that shows that you put in some effort.  But posting something that you're saying you know has no chance of working is kind of wasting everyone's time (including yours).  There are plenty of resources out there showing how to use ajax.

Comment: You could show some of your googling keywords/attempts. It's easiest to help with that if you didn't find anything. (Dunno, but there's likely upwards of 2000 duplicates of this on SO.)

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks for the response.